# Velocity - dynamicaly populating ArrayList

Tags: loops, velocity

Having:

```
#set( $maxVersion = 500 )
```

I'd like to populate list like this:

```
$myList = ("someString_10" "someString_20" "someString_30" ... "someString_500")
```

Any chance to populate it dynamically using velocity template only?

I've seen in the [official docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#variables), there is a support for the lists as well as for the  `#foreach` loop. However it doesn't help here, I'd need kind of for/while specifying the condition to end the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#set ($maxVersions = 500)
#set ($step = 10)
#set ($start = 1)
#set ($count = $maxVersions / $step)
#set ($myList = [])
#foreach ($i in [$start..$count])
  #set ($item = $i * $step)
  #set ($discard = $myList.add("someString_${item}"))
#end

$myList
```

Comment: I solved it another way (outside of velocity template) in the meantime, however once I'll be able to check your solution, will provide more feedback